# Cost of widget Creation in GWT

Tags: gwt

What is the best practice way to manage multi panel (i mean page) application for GWT (in terms of performance, memory usage etc.)
Should i create all widgets and change their visibility or create and remove widget on request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [Large scale Application Development and MVP](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) in terms of best practices to manage a multipage application.

Speaking of re-using Widgets (since they are costly to build) a factory approach to produce them on the fly and keep the instances of costly ones for re-use has worked well for me so far. One thing to keep in mind is to clear the states(values of textboxes etc.) before re-using them. Unless my page is a multi-panel page with hundreds of widgets, I prefer creating them on the fly, instead of re-using, since it has no noticable impact on user performance. I beleive memory should not be an issue unless your app consists of thousands of pages and you keep a reference of each and every single one of them.

Last but not least benefit of using a ClientFactory is you can switch your factory implementation with another-one (ClientFactoryMobile..) with [deffered binding](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) depending on the platform your app is being loaded thus making switching user interfaces a breeze.